# Broken Reference.vb generated after update to VS2012

Tags: vb.net, wcf, dictionary

In my WCF service I have the following OperationContract:

```
<OperationContract()>
Function getResults(ByVal Settings As Dictionary(Of String, String)) As IO.Stream
```

...and MessageContract:

```
<MessageContract()>
Public Class FI
Implements IDisposable

<MessageHeader(MustUnderstand:=True)_
Public id as Integer
<MessageHeader(MustUnderstand:=True)_
Public token as String
<MessageHeader(MustUnderstand:=True)_
Public length as Long
<MessageHeader(MustUnderstand:=True)_
Public del as Char
<MessageHeader(Order:=1)_
Public stream as System.IO.Stream`

Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
FI.Close()
FI=Nothing
End Sub
End Class
```

On the client side after configuring the service in VS and updating I get multiple errors:

1) For `getResults`: Instead of the Dictionary an `ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstringKeyValueOfstringstring` is expected. I already declared the operation contract as `<OperationContract(), ServiceKnownType(GetType(Dictionary(Of String, String)))>` without success. My client settings are CollectionType = Generic.List and DictionaryCollectionType = Generic.Dictionary. I also tried deleting and adding the service again.

2) For `FI`: The method signature that uses the MessageContract FI expects the parameter `del` to be of type Integer. Here I have no idea what to do.

I have to add, that everything was working fine until recently, the only change I can remember is updating Visual Studio from 2010 to 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the underlying problem was an update to .NET 4.5. That's what I did on the machine running VS2010 where the generation *used* to work. **Downgrading to .NET 4.0** did the trick. The generation from within VS is working again.

In conclusion: not a problem of the VS version but of the .NET version of the machine where VS is executed. I guess that the svcutil (or whatever resource the "Update Service Reference" function in VS uses) contained in .NET 4.5 is responsible for the bug.